# How do I specify Http method POST in URI itself?

Tags: rest, http, post, http-post, restful-url

I don't want to use curl, postman, jquery, etc to specify the http method. If I simply put the URL in the browser address bar, it should make a POST request, not GET. Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not, since method is not a part of URL. You could however try and find some browser extension, I would be surprised if there were not a few.

Comment: Another option for consideration - Swagger (http://swagger.io). It can generate interactive html documentation page based on your annotated methods in a code. It automatically detects HTTP methods and method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. As stated by @bereal, the method is not part of the url.

Some workarounds:

- create a simple html page with a `<form method="POST">` that you open locally;
- use the "Cross-Browser Solution" proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-an-xmlhttprequest/38643171#38643171);
- curl or postman are so easy to use, they are worth it;
- if you are developing the API, add a queryParameter like `method=POST` to override the GET request.